# Microsoft Visual Studio Code Terminal – Bash does not stably integrate Python, Conda, and Environments

Tags: bash, terminal, visual-studio-code

I try to make full use of Visual Studio Code,
for which a functional terminal would be very helpful!

The problem is, that every time I reopen the VSC Terminal in Bash,
the settings are deleted, which are in my case integrated Conda and Python into Bash, in Gitbash on my computer this is not the case, there it is stably integrated. 
For now I worked around it by manually integrating Conda and Python every time I open a new Terminal with the following lines of code:

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/c/dev_ops/anaconda:/c/dev_ops/anaconda/Scripts"' >> .profile
echo 'alias python="winpty python.exe"' >> .profile
source .profile
```

Now this is an irqsome quick fix for some use cases, however not for opening or creating environments with conda, because there I would need to restart a Terminal after making changes, and then instead of having it set, it would all be deleted again.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try it with `.bashrc` instead of `.profile`.

Comment: I actually came from .bashrc. with that it did not even stably integrate into my git bash, there was a discussion about this in overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32186840/git-for-windows-doesnt-execute-my-bashrc-file

Comment: OK, so, do you have a `.bash_profile`? Have you tried crating one?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it with .bash_profile as well, in git bash it also did not stably integrate, only .profile does it there. In VSC I have tried all three with the same outcome. I was wondering if there was some administrative action that could be taken in the settings of VSC, however I could not find any.